# How to convert windows console output to utf8 in VIM

Tags: vim

I want to execute a system command from gvim and retrieve the output of that command in the current buffer. So i run the following command in gvim:

```
:r echo éèà
```

However the result shows three black squares instead of the echoed characters. I have not yet figure out what to do to get this to work. I have the following encoding setup:

```
set encoding=utf8
set termencoding=cp850
```

My windows console encoding is cp850.

Comment: I assume you mean `:r! echo éèà`, since without the `!` I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
:r! echo éèà | c:\cygwin\bin\iconv -f cp850 -t cp1252
```

**Assumptions**

I have been able to reproduce your problem on my Windows 10 machine using gvim 7.4, installed via the Windows installer for gvim.

I also have cygwin on my machine, in which I have `iconv`, and its full path is `c:\gygwin\bin\iconv`.

**Proposed solution**

Apparently, gvim expects the output from the Windows shell to be in cp1252 because this worked for me:

```
:r! echo éèà | c:\cygwin\bin\iconv -f cp850 -t cp1252
```

I checked the results, and Vim correctly inserted the utf-8 characters for éèà in my document.

I don't have an equivalent to `iconv` that is Windows native, but if you have Cygwin you can add `c:\cygwin\bin` to your Windows path and the command should not require an explicit path.

**Epilogue**

Yuck. This is ugly. The solution works, at least on my machine, but I hope someone finds and posts a more elegant solution.

There ought to be a way to tell gvim what encoding to expect from the shell, but I did not find it. I played with various combinations of settings of `encoding`, `termencoding` and `fileencoding` instead of using `iconv`, but only managed to get different wrong results.

These related questions faced similar problems but their solutions didn't work in my tests either:

- https://superuser.com/questions/682591/vim-uses-wrong-encoding-when-invoking-commands-in-the-terminal
- https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7105/wrong-encoding-while-calling-shell

The problem stems from the mismatch in character encoding between `cmd.exe` (default `:set shell` in vim on Windows) and what gvim expects. I don't know why changing `:set termencoding` does not fix the problem.

Comment: I installed cygwin and test your solution and it worked nicely.