# Gvim.exe can't open a file including accent characters in its path with '--remote-tab-silent' parameter

Tags: windows, vim, encoding, command-prompt

In cmd.exe on windows7, I can open a file as a new tab in an existing gvim window with '--remote-tab-silent ' option (If no gvim.exe processes exist, only open the file as new gvim.exe process.).

```
gvim.exe -u NONE -p --remote-tab-silent FILE_WITHOUT_ACCENT_CHARS_IN_PATH
```

However, if the file contains accent chars (e.g. é ç ê), gvim.exe opens a different file whose path is equal to accent-removed path from expected one (e.g. c:\éçê --> c:\ece)

The following command-line causes gvim.exe to open the different file from expected one (d:\etre\eeeaaiuuocCei.txt).

```
gvim.exe -u NONE -p -c "set enc=utf-8" --remote-tab-silent "d:\être\éèêàâîùûôçÇëï.txt"
```

The following command-line causes gvim.exe to open the right file, but as a new process / window (I want to use exsiting process).

```
gvim.exe -u NONE -p -c "set enc=utf-8" "d:\être\éèêàâîùûôçÇëï.txt"
```

How can I solve this problem? I use 'gvim_8.1.1140_x64.zip' on 64-bit Win 7.

```
>gvim.exe --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr  8 2019 22:01:49)
```

The problem doesn't occur and the command with `--remote-tab-silent` works perfectly as expected on Ubuntu on GCE.

Comment: I tried to reproduce on my Windows 10 box with gvim 8.1, but it works correctly in my case. So the problem does appear to be specific to Windows 7, for what that's worth.

Comment: PS: you say in the text your use gvim 8.1, but you showed the output of `--version` with 8.0. Which one is correct? Maybe a bug fix in 8.1 applies?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I fixed output of --version. As you say, this may occur only in Windows 7, I had no problems in Windows 10 just now.

Comment: Just tested on a different machine: Windows 7, gvim 7.4. I also don't have the problem there with the first command you show. The second one (with `-c`) has an odd behaviour, opening the wrong file. `cmd.exe` might use cp1252 or even cp850 with strange results in vim sometimes; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54969583/how-to-convert-windows-console-output-to-utf8-in-vim/55151681#55151681. I don't see how to fix your case, but it's certainly an encoding mismatch problem somewhere in the interaction between `cmd` and `gvim`.

Comment: Your suggeting post about `:r!` tells me that the problem occurs in both direction, very useful.
I also think that this problem is caused by encoding mismatch between cmd.exe and (g)vim.exe as you say.
But this aspect seems conflict with success of the command without `--remote-tab-silent` and the same failure after `chcp 650001` in cmd.exe.
I can't break down the issue into parts.

Comment: P.S.
■  I'm sorry that my last test in Win10 had some mistakes... The problem certainly occured also on Win10 just now. And the problem doesn't occur on Ubuntu on GCE (Editted post). 
■ The other special characters (e.g. "が" "й") than french ones don't cause this problem. 
■  The problem also occurs after the command 'chcp 65001' (default is cp932 in my environment)

Comment: I wish Windows would move on from the `cp` encodings and use utf-8 everywhere. There's no excuse in 2019 to stay behind...

Comment: I wish strongly so too.

Comment: For what it's worth, my machine defaults to cp850, which might explain the different behaviours we observe. Do the symptoms remain after a `chcp 850`?

Comment: Thank you for your perseverance, but `chcp850` couldn't eliminate the symptoms  on Win7 / 10. In addition, nothing changes on Powershell, too (I think you might recognized this already).